# Magento2: How to show recently added wishlist to be displayed at the starting In wishlist Page?

Tags: magento2, wishlist, addtowishlist

I want to show a recently added wishlist to be displayed at the starting In wishlist Page in magento2?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `di.xml` file in your custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Customer\Wishlist" />
</config>
```

Now we need to create one Block file here in custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Customer;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist
{
    protected function _prepareCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->setInStockFilter(true)->setOrder('added_at', 'DESC');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I have already tried this, it is not working for me.

Comment: Can you please confirm any other block is not conflicting here which override this same block ? **Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist**

Comment: Or you can use echo die in **_prepareCollection()** function and check.

Comment: okay will check.

Comment: Let me know if you need help then.

Comment: I have remove my custom module, if I change directly in vendor file. it is not changing.

Comment: I am really confused with this.

Comment: Do you have any third party modules ?

Comment: No I am not using any third party modules.

Comment: Which Magento version you have ?

Comment: I am using Magento2.3.0

Comment: I'll check your issue after an hour, I'm little busy with other things so..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101069/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-amy).

Answer (score 0):

_prepareCollection method is not overriding for some reason. So overrided a public function "getWishlistItems" which calls the protected function "_prepareCollection" . Also need to override the private method which is called insided the "getWishlistItems" function. In that way i can able to achieve it. So the required functions inside the above suggested class content by Kishan will be

```
public function getWishlistItems()
{
    if ($this->_collection === null) {
        $this->_collection = $this->_createWishlistItemCollection();
        $this->_prepareCollection($this->_collection);
        $this->paginateCollection();
    }
    return $this->_collection;
}

private function paginateCollection()
{
    $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam("p", 1);
    $limit = $this->getRequest()->getParam("limit", 10);
    $this->_collection
        ->setPageSize($limit)
        ->setCurPage($page);
}

protected function _prepareCollection($collection)
{
    $collection->setInStockFilter(true)->setOrder('added_at', 'DESC');
    return $this;
}
```

It works for me. Hope this will help someone.